# Dojo Form upload does not show text box

Tags: file-upload, dojo

```
<input name="uploadedFile" type="file" id="uploader"  
   data-dojo-type="dojox/form/Uploader" 
   data-dojo-props="style:'height: 26px; width: 75px; '"  label="Browse"  />
```

The above code show only label and Browse button only, not text box. How to show label textbox and browse button respectively.

Answer (score 0):

See the tests here: http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.1/dojo-release-1.8.1/dojox/form/tests/test_Uploader.html

Specify the `showInput:'before'` option in your data-dojo-props.

```
<form method="post" action="UploadFile.php" id="myForm2" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <fieldset>
        <legend>Inline Browse Button Form Post Test</legend>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader" id="uploader2" data-dojo-props="name:'uploadedfile',showInput:'before',isDebug:true">Browse</div>
        <input type="text" name="album" value="Summer Vacation" />
        <input type="text" name="year" value="2011" />
        <input type="button" id="remBtn2" label="Clear" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" />
        <input type="submit" label="Submit" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" />
        <div id="files2" dojoType="dojox.form.uploader.FileList" uploaderId="uploader2"></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I purposefully haven't used `dojox/form/uploader/FileList` since these modules haven't been AMD'ified yet. Although using them with data-dojo-type would work fine, I just wanted to point out this was purposeful.